# Trying do define variable netCDF

Tags: c++, dll, netcdf

I'm new on `netCDF`.

I'm trying to simply define a variable like that:

.nc file example

```
dimensions:

 variables:
    int myvar ;
  myvar:_fillValue = -9999 ;
```

How can i do it?
I know to define a variable with dim id (like that `int myVarWithDim(myDimId)` but without a dim id, i dont know, and i i define the `_fillValue` ? 

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  What resources have you used?  This question is basically asking someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be completely incorrect C++ syntax, 
I'm not sure exactly what you wan't, I'm guesing:

`int _fillValue = -9999 ;`

Which declares a variable called `_fillvalue`, of type `int` and initialises it to the value `-9999`

Comment: hi, @Issac, that is example to .nc file and not a c++ code (i fix the question)